# Atomic read and update in MySQL with concurrent workers

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions

Say I have multiple workers that can concurrently read and write against a MySQL table (e.g. `jobs`). The task for each worker is:

1. Find the oldest `QUEUED` job
2. Set it's status to `RUNNING`
3. Return the corresponding ID.

Note that there may **not** be any qualifying (i.e. `QUEUED`) jobs when a worker runs step #1.

I have the following pseudo-code so far. I believe I need to cancel (`ROLLBACK`) the transaction if step #1 returns no jobs. How would I do that in the code below?

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

# Update the status of jobs fetched by this query:
SELECT id from jobs WHERE status = "QUEUED" 
ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT 1;

# Do the actual update, otherwise abort (i.e. ROLLBACK?)
UPDATE jobs
SET status="RUNNING"
# HERE: Not sure how to make this conditional on the previous ID
# WHERE id = <ID from the previous SELECT>

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Under what circumstances would there be an 'abort' !?!?!?

Comment: It looks like bad idea from the start. Why don't you delegate this job to your end-application ? Its it that should define if something is queued or running, not the database

Comment: Looks like you rather need a single UPDATE statement with ORDER BY and LIMIT.

Comment: @Strawberry I'm interested in canceling the `UPDATE` if there are no jobs with the status `QUEUED`.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasG Not sure I follow. Are you questioning the goal of the question itself? If it helps for context, I'm asking this question as a personal exercise to see how to implement a queue on a DB and thus keeping track (and changing status) of what jobs are waiting to be processed on the DB. I don't see any problem with the goal of the question itself, but if you think this is off-topic or equivalent, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks @PaulSpiegel I'd be curious to see how you would write that (in a **single** `UPDATE` statement), although TBH I'm also interested in how to condition the UPDATE statement to the result of a separate `SELECT` statement in a **transaction** and thus atomic operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am implementing something very similar to your case this week. A number of workers, each grabbing the "next" row in a set of rows to work on.

The pseudocode is something like this:

```
BEGIN;

SELECT ID INTO @id FROM mytable WHERE status = 'QUEUED' LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE;

UPDATE mytable SET status = 'RUNNING' WHERE id = @id;

COMMIT;
```

Using `FOR UPDATE` is important to avoid race conditions, i.e. more than one worker trying to grab the same row.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html for information about `SELECT ... INTO`.

Comment: Thanks -  I didn't know one needs `FOR UPDATE` if it's all part of a transaction. What could happen without `FOR UPDATE`? Also, if we use `FOR UPDATE`, what's the point of wrapping it all in a transaction?

Comment: `SELECT` does no locking without `FOR UPDATE` or `FOR SHARE` (the latter is called `LOCK IN SHARE MODE` before MySQL 8.0). This would allow multiple sessions to read the same `id` value and try to lock it. By using a [locking read](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) you ensure that only one session locks a given row. The others will lock a different row. You still need a transaction because the locks will be released immediately if you use autocommit. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-autocommit-commit-rollback.html

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful Bill.

Comment: If a worker crashes while doing the job? It will left job stuck in status RUNNING forever. Any idea to avoid this?

Comment: @MarcoMarsala You can't avoid it, but you can detect and retry an orphaned job. Run a check periodically for jobs in RUNNING state that haven't been updated in too long. For example, if you expect no job should take more than 10 minutes, then a job in RUNNING for more than 20 minutes is certainly a victim of a crash.

Comment: @BillKarwin - Isn't there a tricky way to use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to turn your transaction into a single IODKU?

Comment: @RickJames I don't have any idea that comes to mind for the purpose in this question. Are you thinking of simulating a sequence? That's in the docs on the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function, but I don't understand how it would be used in this case.

Comment: @BillKarwin - The idea is to (1) assign the task to yourself and (2) retrieve the id in a single IODKU.  (Maybe I am thinking of a related task, and not the specific action the OP is asking about.)

Answer (score 3):

It's still not quite clear what you are after. But assuming your task is: Find the next `QUEUED` job. Set it's status to `RUNNING` and select the corresponding ID.

In a single threaded environment, you can just use your code. Fetch the selected ID into a variable in your application code and pass it to the UPDATE query in the WHERE clause. You don't even need a transaction, since there is only one writing statement. You can mimic in an SQLscript.

Assuming this is your current state:

```
| id  | created_at          | status   |
| --- | ------------------- | -------- |
| 1   | 2020-06-15 12:00:00 | COMLETED |
| 2   | 2020-06-15 12:00:10 | QUEUED   |
| 3   | 2020-06-15 12:00:20 | QUEUED   |
| 4   | 2020-06-15 12:00:30 | QUEUED   |
```

You want to start the next queued job (which has id=2).

```
SET @id_for_update = (
  SELECT id
  FROM jobs
  WHERE status = 'QUEUED'
  ORDER BY id
  LIMIT 1
);

UPDATE jobs
SET status="RUNNING"
WHERE id = @id_for_update;

SELECT @id_for_update;
```

You will get

```
@id_for_update
2
```

from the last select. And the table will have this state:

```
| id  | created_at          | status   |
| --- | ------------------- | -------- |
| 1   | 2020-06-15 12:00:00 | COMLETED |
| 2   | 2020-06-15 12:00:10 | RUNNING  |
| 3   | 2020-06-15 12:00:20 | QUEUED   |
| 4   | 2020-06-15 12:00:30 | QUEUED   |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dCqsBz9JVXweNYyRDTQLvN/0)

If you have multiple processes, which start jobs, you would need to lock the row with `FOR UPDATE`. But that can be avoided using `LAST_INSERT_ID()`:

Starting from the state above, with job 2 already running:

```
UPDATE jobs
SET status = 'RUNNING',
    id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id)
WHERE status = 'QUEUED'
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1;

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

You will get:

```
| LAST_INSERT_ID() | ROW_COUNT() |
| ---------------- | ----------- |
| 3                | 1           |
```

And the new state is:

```
| id  | created_at          | status   |
| --- | ------------------- | -------- |
| 1   | 2020-06-15 12:00:00 | COMLETED |
| 2   | 2020-06-15 12:00:10 | RUNNING  |
| 3   | 2020-06-15 12:00:20 | RUNNING  |
| 4   | 2020-06-15 12:00:30 | QUEUED   |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d1ZjtYQB2tEgBkkD4nBZ1x/0)

If the UPDATE statement affected no row (there were no queued rows) `ROW_COUNT()` will be `0`.

There might be some risks, which I am not aware of - But this is also not really how I would approach this. I would rather store more information in the `jobs` table. Simple example:

```
CREATE TABLE jobs (
  id INT auto_increment primary key,
  created_at timestamp not null default now(),
  updated_at timestamp not null default now() on update now(),
  status varchar(50) not null default 'QUEUED',
  process_id varchar(50) null default null
);
```

and

```
UPDATE jobs
SET status = 'RUNNING',
    process_id = 'some_unique_pid'    
WHERE status = 'QUEUED'
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1;
```

Now a running job belongs to a specific process and you can just select it with

```
SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE process_id = 'some_unique_pid';
```

You might even like to have more information - eg. `queued_at`, `started_at`, `finished_at`.

Comment: It's late so I'm almost certainly missing something, but is any of this actually necessary?

Comment: Thanks Paul - Apologies if my question wasn't clear. I updated the OP. I do have multiple workers that would attempt to concurrently read and write against this table though. Would your answer still work in such scenario? I was under the impression that one 1) should do a transaction / commit to prevent race conditions in this case and 2) cancel it with a rollback if e.g. we don't find any qualifying jobs.

Comment: 1) I wrote in my answer, that you will need to lock the row, when running concurrent processes. A transaction alone doesn't lock. But you need it to keep a (row level) lock until you update the status. But there are also ways to avoid explicit locking - See the other two examples. 2) If there is no QUEUED job, @id_for_update will be NULL and the following UPDATE statement will affect no row (see [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3oBioKf4g41xb64np51fdW/0)). So there is nothing to abbort/rollback.

Comment: @Strawberry What do you mean by "necessary". At least the first example is kind of "basic stuff": Get some info with a SELECT query. Use it in the next query.

Comment: A SELECT is normally for displaying information to an end user. Otherwise the concept of 'first query, next query' is surely rather meaningless

Answer (score 0):

Adding `SKIP LOCKED` to the SELECT query, and putting in a SQL transaction, committed when the job is done, avoid jobs stuck in status RUNNING if a worker crashes (because the uncommitted transaction will rollback). It's now supported in newest versions of most common DBMS.

See:

[Select only unlocked rows mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20091527/select-only-unlocked-rows-mysql)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html#innodb-locking-reads-nowait-skip-locked

Comment: Do not use an InnoDB transaction for any but very short tasks.  The `lock_wait_timeout` default of 50 seconds is much too long.

Comment: With SKIP LOCKED shouldn’t be an issue, it isn’t?

Comment: Since I don't understand what cases can safely use `SKIP LOCKED`, I avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

(This is not an answer to the question, but a list of caveats that you need to be aware of when using any of the real Answers.  Some of these have already been mentioned.)

- Replication -- You must do all the locking on the Primary.  If you are using a cluster with multiple writable nodes, be aware of the inter-node delays.
- Backlog -- When something breaks, you could get a huge list of tasks in the queue.  This may lead to some ugly messes.
- Number of 'workers' -- Don't have more than a "few" workers.  If you try to have, say, 100 concurrent workers, they will stumble over each other an cause nasty problems.
- Reaper -- Since a worker may crash, the task assigned to it may never get cleared.  Have a `TIMESTAMP` on the rows so a separate (cron/EVENT/whatever) job can discover what tasks are long overdue and clear them.
- If the tasks are fast enough, then the overhead of the queue could be a burden.  That is, "Don't queue it, just do it."
- You are right to grab the task in one transaction, then *later* release the task in a *separate* transaction.  Using InnoDB's locking is folly for any be trivially fast actions.